# Piping the output of wget into grep to select lines

Tags: grep, wget

There's a large file that I need to download, but it's too big to fit on the server (~1Tb), so instead I'd like to only keep lines that I need, which are found in a pattern text file.

```
wget www.foo.com/file.txt | grep -f file.txt
```

The pattern text file contains patterns like `bar` and the large text file would be like

```
test blah blah foo
blah test bar blah
```

I've tried various combinations of this but none of them retained the right lines in the file. Is this possible?

Comment: What is actually extracted with your `grep` if not the lines that contains the matches of the patterns in `file.txt`?  It is difficult to debug your issue since we don't know what's happening and have no way of testing your code to try to reproduce the issue for ourselves.  Is it _only_ the fact that `wget` saves the file to disk by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way with STDOUT (`wget -q URL -O-`) and the search pattern in a file runs without problems:

```
echo HERR > /tmp/search.txt
echo Frau >> /tmp/search.txt
wget -q https://archive.org/stream/DieBibel-AltesUndNeuesTestament-NachMartinLuther/DieBibel-Deutsch-Pdf_djvu.txt -O- | grep -f /tmp/search.txt
```